I want to change the color of radio button
When I use the colors blue, red, and green, everything works fine.
However, when I use orange or the color code #fb0, a black radius appears in the middle section.



accent-color: red
accent-color: #fb0









input[type=radio] {
    accent-color: #fb0;
    /* ... */
}


I don't think you can change this using CSS, and as far as I know, it's a browser-defined behavior (see https://accent-color.glitch.me).

It may not be an exact duplicate, so I will link instead: How do I change the color of radio buttons?. It has lots of answers and alternative approaches, and should explain why styling radio buttons the way you want ranges from "not easy" to "you need a custom substitute".

If that inner ring was white it would not contrast well with yellow so that's probably why it's dark.

Yes, that’s an annoying behaviour of Chrome. Safari renders it very nicely, as follows. For more control, implement custom radio buttons.



label {
  display: block;
}

input[type=radio][value="1"] {
  accent-color: #f00;
}

input[type=radio][value="2"] {
  accent-color: #fb0;
}

input[type=radio][value="3"] {
  accent-color: #080;
}

input[type=radio][value="4"] {
  accent-color: #00f;
}
<label><input type="radio" value="1" checked> One</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="2" checked> Two</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="3" checked> Three</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="4" checked> Four</label>



